# JS: Sort List Items based on data-element

Tags: javascript, list, sorting

**I want to sort a list with items. The sorting should be based on the data-element of each item.**

The strange thing is, it **works if you try it locally** on your pc (download my sortingtest.html), **but it doesn't work** online in jfiddle, neither and more importantly on mobile phones!

Do you have an idea whats wrong with my code or how I could do it better so that it works also on mobile phones?

**The Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function sortEntries() {    
        var elems = $('#mylist').children('li').remove();
        elems.sort(function(a,b){ 
            return parseInt($(b).data('vote')) > parseInt($(a).data('vote'));
        });
        $('#mylist').append(elems);
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <ul id="mylist">
        <li data-vote="2">Vote: 2</li>
        <li data-vote="4">Vote: 4</li>
        <li data-vote="1">Vote: 1</li>
        <li data-vote="5">Vote: 5</li>
        <li data-vote="3">Vote: 3</li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#" onClick="sortEntries();">Sort me!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**JFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Q82Qu/

**HTML-File Download:** (Save file as)
https://copy.com/c0Ogb8wLtRrg

Big thanks in advance,
Stee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sorted it out on my own:

The key is to use this sorting code:

```
elems.sort(function(a,b){ 
    return $(b).attr('data-vote') - $(a).attr('data-vote');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var elems = $('#mylist').children('li').remove();
```

what above code do is remove `DOM` from the Document so you can not use it as `elems.sort(`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    function sortEntries()
    {
        var elems = $('#mylist').children('li');
        elems.sort(function(a,b){ 
            return parseInt($(b).data('vote')) > parseInt($(a).data('vote'));
        });
        $('#mylist').append(elems);
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <ul id="mylist">
        <li data-vote="2">Vote: 2</li>
        <li data-vote="4">Vote: 4</li>
        <li data-vote="1">Vote: 1</li>
        <li data-vote="5">Vote: 5</li>
        <li data-vote="3">Vote: 3</li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#" onClick="sortEntries();">Sort me!</a>

</body>
</html>
```